# jQuery UI ThemeRoller Developer Tool

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, developer-tools, themeroller

What is 'jQuery UI ThemeRoller Developer Tool' Use For ?

I have this tool as the [jQuery website said](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/) to Firefox toolbar.
it said :

after that i opened a website. i clicked on the jQuery UI ThemeRoller on toolbar.
jQuery Theme Roller Opened. but after i clicked on every Theme nothing has happened.
how can i use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery ThemeRoller Developer Tool allows you to style jQuery elements on any website that uses jQuery CSS3 for styling. Just add it to your bookmarks, and then select it if you want to re-style and existing jQuery site.

Here is a decent overview:
http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/introducing_the_themeroller_firefox_developer_bookmarklet/

Note:

In the comments you will see that it is broken in some versions of FireFox. Here is one of the proposed workarounds:

1. Download the developertools.js file mentioned in the bookmarklet
2. Wrap the values of all href attribute selectors in single quotes, e.g. [href=foo] becomes [href=’foo’]
3. Host the modified developertools.js somewhere.
4. Update your bookmarklet to point to your modified developertools.js

Comment: Thanks, was struggling to figure out how to fire it up, was dragging it to the tool bar and nothing appeared!  Makes sense once you see it working to grab it from the bookmarks on the page you're interested in

Answer (score 3):

I've found a nice fix for this problem on [JQuery Forums](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/the-firefox-themeroller-bookmarklet-does-not-update-the-html-page-when-changing-theme-colors). Since it was a little bit outdated, it wasn't working for FF versions above 10.
Posted a fix there, and also posting over here, maybe someone finds it useful:

Replace the bookmarklet source with this code:

```
javascript:(function(){if(!/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)){alert("Sorry,%20due%20to%20security%20restrictions,%20this%20tool%20only%20works%20in%20Firefox");return%20false}else{if(window.jquitr){jquitr.addThemeRoller()}else{jquitr={};jquitr.s=document.createElement("script");jquitr.s.src="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/developertool/developertool.js.php";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(jquitr.s);var%20a=function(){jquitr.reloadCSS=function(){var%20c=jquitr.getHash(),b;if(jquitr.trString!==c&&c!==""){jquitr.trString=c;b='<link%20href="http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/css/parseTheme.css.php?'+c+'"%20type="text/css"%20rel="Stylesheet"%20/>';if($("link[href*='parseTheme.css.php'],%20link[href='ui.theme.css']").size()>0){$("link[href*='parseTheme.css.php']:last,%20link[href='ui.theme.css']:last").eq(0).after(b)}else{$("head").append(b)}if($("link[href*='parseTheme.css.php']").size()>3){$("link[href*='parseTheme.css.php']:first").remove()}}window.setTimeout(jquitr.reloadCSS,1000)};jquitr.reloadCSS()};window.setTimeout(a,1100)}}})();
```

This will replace the faulty code after 1.1s after you click on the bookmark and Themeroller will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

The themeroller is to make your own theme for JQuery UI, I believe you can use that themeroller addon on sites that are using JQuery UI, to download their themes and change them.

Just try it out on:
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/
and see what you can do by clicking on themes in the gallery or changing stuff, also look at the url in your browser when you click on a gallery theme.

Lauw